# PHPUnit assertSame, assertEquals on not equals strings give Error " Uncaught PHP Exception Exception: "Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed""

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony, phpunit

```
public function testTest(){
    $this->assertEquals("1", "2");   
}
```

This code give error

```
PHPUnit 9.3.10 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

E                                                                   1 / 1 (100%)

Time: 00:01.793, Memory: 8.00 MB

There was 1 error:

1) Mb\ArticleBundle\Tests\Controller\ArticleControllerAdminTest::testTest
PHPUnit\Framework\Exception: 2020-09-25T13:18:08+02:00 [critical] Uncaught PHP Exception Exception: "Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed" at C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\PHP7D5C.tmp line 275
2020-09-25T13:18:08+02:00 [critical] Exception thrown when handling an exception (Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException: The "kernel" service is synthetic, it needs to be set at boot time before it can be used. at D:\MY_WEBSITE\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container.php line 334)
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Exception: Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed in C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\PHP7D5C.tmp:275
Stack trace:
#0 C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\PHP7D5C.tmp(275): serialize(Array)
#1 C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\PHP7D5C.tmp(740): __phpunit_run_isolated_test()
#2 {main}

Next Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException: The "kernel" service is synthetic, it needs to be set at boot time before it can be used. in D:\MY_WEBSITE\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container.php:334
Stack trace:
#0 D:\MY_WEBSITE\var\cache\test\ContainerFhj8wps\appTestProjectContainer.php(4022): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get('kernel', 1)
#1 D:\MY_WEBSITE\var\cache\test\ContainerFhj8wps\appTestProjectContainer.php(4125): ContainerFhj8wps\appTestProjectContainer->getTemplating_LocatorService()
#2 D:\MY_WEBSITE\var\cache\test\ContainerFhj8wps\appTestProjectContai in D:\MY_WEBSITE\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container.php on line 334
Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed in C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\PHP7D5C.tmp:275
Stack trace:
#0 C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\PHP7D5C.tmp(275): serialize(Array)
#1 C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\PHP7D5C.tmp(740): __phpunit_run_isolated_test()
#2 {main}

Next Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException: The "kernel" service is synthetic, it needs to be set at boot time before it can be used. in D:\MY_WEBSITE\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container.php:334
Stack trace:
#0 D:\MY_WEBSITE\var\cache\test\ContainerFhj8wps\appTestProjectContainer.php(4022): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get('kernel', 1)
#1 D:\MY_WEBSITE\var\cache\test\ContainerFhj8wps\appTestProjectContainer.php(4125): ContainerFhj8wps\appTestProjectContainer->getTemplating_LocatorService()
#2 D:\MY_WEBSITE\var\cache\test\ContainerFhj8wps\appTestProjectContai in D:\MY_WEBSITE\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container.php on line 334

ERRORS!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Errors: 1.
```

When strings are not equals, test give this error. But when strings are equals it pass. Only when i want to comprare strings which are not equals i get this error.
When i comprare different integers, test show failed result but without error.
Any help?

phpunit.xml.dist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html -->
<phpunit
    backupGlobals               = "false"
    backupStaticAttributes      = "false"
    colors                      = "true"
    convertErrorsToExceptions   = "true"
    convertNoticesToExceptions  = "true"
    convertWarningsToExceptions = "true"
    processIsolation            = "false"
    stopOnFailure               = "false"
    bootstrap                   = "autoload.php" >

    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Project Test Suite">
            <directory>../src/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
            <directory>../src/*/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
            <directory>../src/*/Bundle/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>

    <!--
    <php>
        <server name="KERNEL_DIR" value="/path/to/your/app/" />
    </php>
    -->


</phpunit>
```

Comment: Hi, could you share the phpunit.xml files, please?

Comment: Yes, I added in post